# Tensorflow server returns an error when using model on S3

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, tensorflow-serving

I'm experimenting with the tensorflow server and I succeeded to request the half_plus_two model example in the most simple setting (see docs [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving)). By simple setting I mean here embedding the model (more precisely the directory which contains a version subdir and all the model files under this subdir) in my docker container and starting the tensorflow_model_server either with model_name and model_base_path as parameters or with model_config file parameter.

When I try to put model on S3 (private S3 storage, not AWS), the server starts and finds the model as seen in the logs:

```
I tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:403] File- 
system polling update: Servable:{name: half_plus_two version: 1}; Servable path: 
s3://tftest/half_plus_two/1; Polling frequency: 1
```

The request to the model does not succeed anymore though. The error I get is :

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value b\n\t [[{{node b/read}}]]
```

It's like if using S3 does not let enough time to the model to initialize its values. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sort it out. The problem was that the S3 content was not correct. It was containing all the files needed (ok) + the directories (not ok). Source of the problem was my copy procedure from GCP to S3. This procedure is based on google.cloud storage client. So when I did:

```
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucketName, prefix=savedDir)
```

and looped over the blobs to copy each object in S3, I was also copying directories. Apparently the S3 connector from tensorflow-server was not liking it.